# How to disable Caching in CORS-Anywhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, csrf, cors-anywhere

I am running into `CSRF token validation failed` error when trying to do a `POST` request on an endpoint which is on a different server using `cors-anywhere`. Its mostly because the CSRF Token that I am passing to the cors-server is cached and hence the validation fails.

I have read the following **Stack Overflow** link - [Similar issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159969/csrf-not-working-over-cors-proxy/166007)
. Turns out my problem is same as the one in the link but since that link does not contain any solution I am asking it here.

Please help.

**EDIT:-**

```
                  $.ajax({
                          async: false,
                          crossDomain: true,
                          data: batch_request,
                          url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://......api.s4hana.ondemand.com:xxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV;v=0002/$batch",
                          type: "POST",
                          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "xxxxxxxxx");
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed;boundary=batch");
                          },
                          success:function(response) {
                              console.log("Succesfully added new contacts");
                              console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                              console.log("Error");
                              console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
```

I have made a GET call using POSTMAN and retrieved the CSRF token from the server. For now, I have hardcoded the token in the AJAX call. I receive the following error when I do it-

[image: Error]

Comment: In the question you are referring to it is a GET request, but yours is a POST, and with those there usually are no such caching issues - so I rather doubt whether your problem analysis is actually correct here. Perhaps the token is tied to the requesting client IP address or something like that, and that’s what actually makes it fail …?

Comment: Or are you talking about caching in regard to an initial GET request that fetches the token in the first place? Well then any old standard run-of-the-mill cache busting (like appending the current timestamp as an additional query string parameter) should probably do the trick.

Comment: I dont think I have mentioned any GET request. I am making a POST request which contains a CSRF token that was fetched from the server via a GET call. The resulting response from the server says that CSRF validation failed. So, I open up Postman, make a GET call to fetch the CSRF token and now I hard code this CSRF token in the POST call which the browser makes. Again, the post call fails.

Comment: Another thing to note. In Postman whenever I make a GET call to fetch the CSRF token it returns the same token (for atleast an hour). But when I do the same thing via browser (using cors-anywhere), I receive a new token for each GET call that I make.

Comment: _“it returns the same token (for atleast an hour)”_ - and that token also works for multiple requests then? _“But when I do the same thing via browser (using cors-anywhere), I receive a new token for each GET call that I make”_ - a _different_ value every time does not sound like a caching issue to me.

Comment: Okay so if its not a caching issue then why does the CSRF validation fail ? Do you want me to post the ajax code ?

Comment: Maybe due to the involvement of the CORS proxy in itself … (If that remote site actually wanted you to be able to do this, would they not enable CORS from their end then?) I’d try and make the request without the proxy, using a browser extension that allows you to circumvent the CORS restrictions, and see if it works then.

Comment: I have installed Allow-Access-Origin Browser plugin but that does not work at the moment. That's why I had to resort to using Cors-Anywhere. Anyway, I updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: How exactly does it not work using the plugin? Same error regarding the CSRF token, or something else? The code does not look off at a glance; but I would perhaps verify whether the proxy actually passes along all those request headers properly (by having it send to a script of your own, that logs these headers) first.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF validation depends on matching two tokens associated with the request. Typically one is in the request itself and the other is stored in a session associated with the request by a cookie.

Since you are going through a simple proxy, you are anonymising yourself and there is no session associated with the request.

---

If you want to work around this, then you would need to write your own server-side proxy which maintained the session on a per-user basis.